# Casting to a derived type in entity framework code first

Tags: inheritance, orm, casting, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm using EntityFramework 6, code first, with MVC C#.
I have a couple of simple entities that looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person {
    public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

You get the idea. The problem I have is when an existing person in the database becomes an Employee. So I already have a Person record associated with them, but now they have become an employee so now they need an Employee record. I don't see any way to do this with EF. What I would like to be able to do is something like the following:

```
Person person = GetPerson();
Employee employee = (employee)person;
context.Employees.Add(employee);
SaveChanges();
```

But C# doesn't let you cast a base type to a sub type, so I can't do that, and if I create a new Employee record then Entity framework will create a new Person record too. Does anyone know of a simple way to achieve this? I think the design is right, in that Employee ***is a*** Person, so inheritance over composition is surely the right choice for this case.

I could write some SQL myself to insert the record I need into the Employee table, or I could delete the old record and replace it with a new one (which would come with a whole load of foreign key problems), but if I do that I'm accepting that Entity Framework has essentially failed me for a pretty simple and common requirement. Is there no way around this?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Why you can't simply create `new Employee()` and then copy all corresponding properties from `person`? Perhaps EF will not create new `Person`, if existed `person` already attached to same context and you have proper `Id` field for `employee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that the tables and their columns are not really clear to you.

Every object in the database has a primary key used to identify the properties of the object. The properties of the object might change, the thing that the object represents will be the same thing.

A Person might change his address, he might even change his name, sex or birthday, for the database it remains the same Person. Only if you change his Id, it really becomes a different Person.

Apparently you have `Persons` that are not yet an `Employee`. If the `Person` starts working for you, does that mean that he becomes a different `Person`? Should his Id change?

You could decide that if the `Person` with Id 10 becomes an `Employee`, you create an `Employee` object with the Id 10, and if this `Person` also becomes a `Customer` you create a `Customer` object with Id 10. If the `Employee` stops working for you, you remove the `Employee` with Id 10 and keep the `Person` and `Customer` with Id 10.

Although this could work, it would require you to do your own Id-numbering. The database can hardly check if you do illegal things, like kiling a `Person` that is still one of your `Employees`.

Instead of having one Id to identify your `Employee`, your `Person` and your `Customer`, give them all their own Primary Key. Give `Employee` and `Customer` a foreign key to the `Person` they are. In fact, the Person is more something like `PersonData`. An Employee IS not a Person, an Employee HAS Person data

```
class PersonData // your old Person
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     ...
}
class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Employee has PersonData using foreign key
    public int PersonDataId {get; set;}
    public virtual PersonData PersonData {get; set;}
    ...
}
class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Customerhas PersonData using foreign key
    public int PersonDataId {get; set;}
    public virtual PersonData PersonData {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

This won't change your three tables: every table has a primary Key named Id. Employees and Customers have a foreign key to the PersonData table. You might need some fluent API though, to match column names if you already have a database (not really code-first is it?).

**Back to your question**

You have an existing Person, identified by his Id, and he starts working for you: you just add a new Employee, with foreign key to this Person

```
var addedEmployee = myDbcontext.Employees.Add(new Employee()
{
     PersonId = PersonId,
     ...
})
```

If this Person will also have a different job, just add a new Employee with the same PersonId. If he decides to quit the old function: remove the old employee, but keep the new one intact. If a different Person will perform the functions of this Employee: only change the PersonId. If the Employee also becomes a Customer: add a new Customer with PersonId equal to the PersonId of the Employee.

IMHO this solution is way simpler and more natural than the solution where you try to keep the Employee / Customer / Person with the same value for primary key. If you still want this, read [Entity Framework Table Per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)